# Meshlab texture.png is blank

Tags: meshlab

I have imported a point cloud from VisualSFM to Meshlab, and created a Poisson surface.  On the right side of Meshlab, the layers are listed and the color photo file names from which the model was created are also listed.  With the Poisson layer highlighted, I try to use Filters-> Texture -> Parameterization+Rasterization to create the texture.png file.  The texture.png file that results shows only black outlines where the images should be (see Mr. P's tutorial on Parameterization and Rasterization or other examples on the Web).  The images themselves are all white.  I have tried this in Meshlab 2014 and 2016.  The procedure I've followed is the same as many other examples on the Web using VisualSFM and Meshlab.  Anyone have a clue as to why the texture.png file is basically blank?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Could be how you open the .nvm.cmvs file in MeshLab. Select the bundle.rd.out file in the "00" folder, it will lead you to open the List.txt file, which will import all the images into MeshLab & generate a point cloud (0-model)(make sure vertices are showing to view model). Then File > Import Mesh & shift select all the "option-000*.ply" files in the ".nvm.cmvs>00>models" folder & import into MeshLab. It imports each to individual layers, so you need to hide the 0-model layer, make sure all .ply layers are visible, right click on one, select "Flatten Layers" and check the box "keep unregistered vertices" & uncheck "delete Layers" unless you duplicate first and hide as spares. MeshLab will merge the meshes into one. Check for non-manifold edges/faces etc then texture using Parameterization + texturing from registered rasters. Works fine for me.

Comment: this is not a good answer refer this link for good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I read the "how-to-answer" guide and curious to know how I could improve the answer to meet the guidelines. I'm new to forum & not a coder, so this noob needs some more info please.